# Quickest way to copy text in a pdf

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, vim, pdf, foxit-reader

I'm looking for the most efficient way to copy text from a pdf using only my keyboard.

I want to emulate what I do in Vim, which is to place my cursor at the point where I would like to begin my selection by using the search function (.e.g, typing the first few letters of a word), then extend the selection from that point and copy the text.

So far, the most success I've had was in [I'm using Foxit, version 1.1.1.0301](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/).  I will describe what I tried in Foxit below.

After searching for a word with cmd+f in Foxit, shift+left/right does nothing.  Shift+left/right would normally extend the selection if some characters were already highlighted.

Further, selecting a word with cmd+f, then hitting cmd+6 (Tools > Select text) or escape deselects the word.

Is there a way to accomplish what I've described?

If not, I suppose my best alternative is to use cmd+6 (Tools > Select text), which allows me to move around the text with my keyboard ([Caret Navigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_navigation)).  Then I can place my cursor where I'd like to begin my selection, then make my selection with shift+left/right.  Are there are other pdf readers besides Foxit that would allow me to select/copy text in this way?

OS:  Mac, El Capitan